# Problem with right recursive rules with Bison

Tags: c, recursion, bison, yacc, rules

I have implemented with bison the management of a multidimensional array
this piece of code works, using the left recursive rules
however. The manual indicates that it is preferable to use those on the right. link : [Bison Recursive Rules](https://perso.esiee.fr/~najmanl/compil/Bison/bison_toc.html#SEC42)

now, however, if I use the right rule, the array is not parsed correctly.
the problem is that when I use the right rule, the internal array a[2,3] returns 4 dimensions instead of 2 and the other array x[,] have no dimension.

my question is : why this piece of code does not work with right recursive rule ?

incorrect recursive erroneous rule:

```
argList
    : expr              {stackNode [ kstack++ ] = $1 ;  }
    | argList ',' expr  {stackNode [ kstack++ ] = $3 ;  }
```

sample source:

```
xy[1, a[2,3] ] =  4  ;
```

grammar of bison:

```
argList
    : expr              {stackNode [ kstack++ ] = $1 ;  }
    | expr ',' argList  {stackNode [ kstack++ ] = $1 ;  }
;   

statement                                                
    : tPV
    | expr tPV  { $$=$1; } 
;

expr
    : tINTEGER                  { $$ = new_tINTEGER ( $1 ) ;    }
    | tID '[' argList ']'
    {   
        void** n=(void**) malloc ( sizeof(void**)*kstack ) ;    
        for(int j=0,  i=kstack-1    ;   i>=0    ;   i-- )   n[j++] = (void*) stackNode[i] ;
        $$ = new_tArrayArgList ( $1,kstack,n ) ;
        kstack=0;
    }   
    | expr tEQ      expr            { $$ = new_tBINOP ( tEQ,$1,$3) ;    /*  =   */}
```

reference link:

[How to build an Array with Bison/Yacc and a Recursive Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429794/how-to-build-an-array-with-bison-yacc-and-a-recursive-rule)

[Left Recursive Rules in Context Free Grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198080/left-recursive-rules-in-context-free-grammar)

Regards
Claudio

Comment: Please be clearer about how the parse failed to meet your expectations. If the issue you have is that your stack is filled in backwards, that is to be expected because of the order in which the reductions are made.

Comment: the problem is that when I use the right recursive rule, the internal array a[2,3] returns 4 dimensions instead of 2. else with left recursive rules both dimension or array are right. ( update question )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the global varaibles `stackNode` and `kstack` to track argument lists.  This is not reentrant, so when you have nested argument lists, processing the inner list absorbs and corrupts the state of the outer list, resulting in garbage.  This is independent of left- vs right- recursion, though the two cases will show different corruption.

The solution is to not use globals -- return the necessary values in `$$`:

```
argList
    : expr              { $$ = new_empty_deque();
                          push_back($$, $1);  }
    | expr ',' argList  { $$ = $3; push_front($$, $1); }
;
```

alternately (and superior), use a left-recursive rule:

```
argList
    : expr              { $$ = new_empty_deque();
                          push_back($$, $1);  }
    | argList ',' expr  { $$ = $1; push_back($$, $3); }
;
```

Comment: I have implemented a local stack and now work (right or left recursive ), as you indicated to me, thank you.